# ASP.NET hide referrer hostname via code in Response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect, referrer

I redirect users to another site from my site https://www.example.com like so:

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.targetsite.com")
```

However, for privacy of my visitors I don't want the receiving site to see that the traffic came from my site. Basically strip the `referrer hostname` value or replace it with another string, e.g. "unknown".

Is it possible and if so, how? I prefer to do this via code (because I only want to do it for some sites) and not via web.config/url rewrite.

I Googled, [I found something here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-do-i-hide-referrer-info-to-linked-external-sites-779293508.html), but it's either via javascript (which I don't want) or via rewrites. I can't find anything that applies to my requirements.

Comment: I think adding response header “Referrer-Policy: no-referrer” might be what you need.

Comment: That works! Just to be sure: I don't see my source server's IP address in the referrer data, is that not passed somewhere too?

Comment: Shouldn’t be. The request to targetsite.com will come from the users’ browser.